# How to detect when a specific object moves out of frame in an opencv program?

Tags: python, opencv, time, state-machine

I'm currently practicing opencv and tried the face recognition code and it's working fine. I'd like to get notified if I'm away from the screen for more than 2 mins. I'm trying to play an audio file when I'm away and stop it when I'm back.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE  
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('Video', frame)
    
    # check if the tuple faces is empty
    if len(faces) == 0:
      start_time = time.time()
      while len(faces) == 0:
        print('person is away for ',time.time()-start_time)
        d_time = time.time()
        if d_time-start_time > 120:
            pygame.mixer.init()
            sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Recording.mp3")
            sound.play(5)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you are expected to attempt to solve your question and show what you tried. -- this is "just" programming 101. you need to look at the time, and you need to have a state variable.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check if `faces` is empty for a certain amount of time

Comment: @Abhinesh Prakash you can use `OpenCV object tracker` to track the movement of face and determine whether the person has moved out of camera view

Comment: @Jeru Luke, I checked if faces are empty or not using len(faces), but I find it difficult to check it within a certain amount of time.

Comment: @AbineshPrakash Start the timer a soon the webcam starts reading the first frame (at the start of `while` loop). Every time there is no face store the time and for every consecutive frame that has no face check the time difference. And when it exceeds 120 seconds play your file.

Comment: @JeruLuke, I added a while loop to check the time difference between consecutive frames. Now the video capture is not responding as soon as it opens and it is not able to capture any feed. What is causing this error?